# The sum of the values in the request

Tags: sql, interbase

```
select sum(SUMM_PRIH) from DOC_PR WHERE DATA_PRIH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' and kod in ('020047', '020045')
  UNION ALL
select sum(SUMM_OPL) from DOC_RA WHERE DATA_RASH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' and kod in ('020112', '020116')
```

I get 2 values,how can I calculate the sum of these values immediately in the request ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add move the expressions to the `from` clause and then add them:

```
select x1.sum1 + x2.sum2
from (select sum(SUMM_PRIH) as sum1 from DOC_PR WHERE DATA_PRIH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' and kod in ('020047', '020045')) x1 cross join
     (select sum(SUMM_OPL) as sum2 from DOC_RA WHERE DATA_RASH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' and kod in ('020112', '020116')) x2;
```

Actually, the sums are from the same table, so you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select ( sum(case when DATA_PRIH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' and kod in ('020047', '020045')
                  then SUMM_PRIH else 0
             end) +
        sum(case when DATA_RASH between '01.01.2020 00:00:00' and '01.02.2020 23:59:59' and kod in ('020112', '020116')
                 then SUMM_OPL else 0
            end)
        )
from DOC_RA ;
```

I would encourage you to use standard date formats.  Your date comparisons are probably better written something like this:

```
DATA_RASH >= '2020-01-01' and
DATE_RASH < '2020-01-03'
```

Comment: Error Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, char 5.
select.

Comment: @Федотов . . . Oops.  I left the column names out of the first query.